# Is there a way to prioritize line breaks in an Android TextView

Tags: java, android

So I have a textview that receives a string via .setText(string);

is there any way to set line wrap / break behavior.

Split on ' ' highest
Split on '/' middle
Split on ':' lowest
Split on '\u00A0' never

If need be I can parse the string myself getting width of the view and width of each character but I was hoping there was something a little less intensive.

Thanks